# Applying k-folds (stratified 10-fold) to my text classification model

Tags: classification, cross-validation, text-classification, n-gram, k-fold

I need help in the following, I have a data frame with Columns: Class (0,1) and text.
After cleansing (lemmatizing, removing stopwords, etc), I split the data like the following:

```
#splitting datset

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset['text_lemm_nostop'], dataset['class'],test_size=0.3, random_state=50)
```

Then I used n-gram:

```
#using n-gram

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vect=CountVectorizer(min_df=5,ngram_range=(2,2), max_features=5000).fit(X_train) 
print('No. of features:')
len(vect.get_feature_names_out()) # how many features
```

Then I did the vectorizing:

```
X_train_vectorized=vect.transform(X_train)
X_test_vectorized=vect.transform(X_test)
```

Then I started applying ML algorithms like (logistic regression, Naive Bayes, RF,..etc)
and I will share only the logistic regression

```
#Logistic regression

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
model=LogisticRegression()
model.fit(X_train_vectorized, y_train)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn import metrics 
predictions=model.predict(vect.transform(X_test))
print("AUC Score is: ", roc_auc_score(y_test, predictions),'\n')
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, predictions),'\n')
print('Classification Report:\n',classification_report(y_test,predictions))
```

**My Questions:**

**1. Is what I am doing is fine in case I am going with normal splitting (30% test)?**
(I feel having issues with n-gram code!)

**2. If I want to engage the K-fold cross-validation (ie. Stratified 10-fold), how could I do that in my code?**

**Appreciate any help and support!!**

Comment: Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

- Generally I don't see any obvious mistake, seems fine to me.
- Do you really mean to use only bigrams (n=2)? This implies that you don't use unigrams (single words), so you might miss some information this way. It's more common to use `ngram_range=(1,2)` for instance. It's probably worth trying unigrams only, at least to compare the performance.
- To perform 10-fold cross-validation, I'd suggest you use [KFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold) because it's the simplest method. In this case it's almost the same code, except that you insert it inside a loop which iterates the 10 folds. Every time you fit the model on a specific training set (90%) and evaluate it on the remaining 10% test set. Both training and test set are obtained by selecting the corresponding indexes indexes returned by `KFold`.

Comment: can you help in the k-fold code?

Comment: Do I have to insert all n-gram code and the model fitting inside the loop?

Comment: @FirasK. Yes, exactly. The principle of k-fold CV is that the whole process of training + testing is done at every iteration with a different split of training + test data.

Comment: Thank you Erwan, If some one could help in the code it will be great help and support!

Comment: @FirasK. you can try to do it and if you have a problem with the code you can ask again.